# Get Tab Selection Event from UITabBar in a ViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

The structure of my MainStoryboard is:

```
->Tab Bar Controller -> Navigation Controller -> View Controller (Search)
```

The behaviour I want to have is that when the user re-selects the Search tab, the UIScrollView on it scrolls to the top. I am unsure how to get the event from the TabBarController, however.

I've been looking at a lot of stuff about UITabBarDelegate, particularly:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

I have, not quite  managed to get this to work properly though. I am very unsure about how to go about setting the delegate (assuming that is the way it's done). I've tried hooking it up in IB, but it wouldn't let me. I also tried to get the UITabBar from the AppDelegate (after looking at some seemingly-related answers).

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated (unless they're null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UITabBar *aTabBar = [UITabBarItem alloc] init];
```

....Any other modifications you want to make to aTabBar....

```
[aTabBar setDelegate:self]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add "`<UITabBarDelegate>`" to the "`@interface`" part of whatever object you're trying to designate as the delegate.

For my own code, I usually use some object that *isn't* the application delegate (as the app delegate is usually meant for application level events like "application is suspending" or "application is coming back into foreground").  If you add "`<UITabBarDelegate>`" to your Search view controller, make sure that whatever you do with the "`didSelectItem`" method is applicable only to the Search view controller.  Otherwise instantiate some different object if you want to do actions on various view controllers based on which tab bar item is being displayed.

Comment: I have <UITabBarDelegate> on my Search View Controller. I'd like to know how to actually set it as the delegate though. Nothing I've tried seems to have done that.